# How to convert to / get RFC822 date in bash/linux?

Tags: linux, bash, rfc822

Looking at `date`'s man page, I couldn't find a standard way to convert to rfc822 (eg: from unix timestamp). I took a brief look at the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5.1), but I don't know enough about the subject matter to get the format right. Is there a easy way to convert to rfc822 with standard linux terminal tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `man 1 date`:

> `-R, --rfc-email`
>
> output date and time in RFC 5322 format.
> Example: Mon, 14 Aug 2006 02:34:56 -0600

And it looks like [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322):

> [...] is a revision of Request For Comments (RFC) 2822, which itself superseded
> Request For Comments (RFC) 822 [...]

Short answer use `date -R` (and `-d @<unix>` for the unix timestamp). For example, in my machine just now:

```
$ date -R
Mon, 11 Sep 2017 20:41:30 +0200
$ date -R -d @1505155314
Mon, 11 Sep 2017 20:41:54 +0200
```